# merging of launch files

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 2 launch files which are launching same node but one launches with namespace and other with no namespace. how do I combine both of them? is it possible to make namespace argument optional ?

launch_file1 :

```
<node pkg="node_pkg" type="node_type" name="node_name" >
```

launch_file2:

so i am launching same node with no_namespace and with namespace.

```
<node pkg="node_pkg" type="node_type" name="node_name"   if="$(arg use_namespace)" ns="$(arg namespace)">
```

so i combined both launch files with above line in one single launch file. and i am using use_namespace to specify whether i want to launch node with namespace or not. but now it is launching nodes with onyl namespace my understanding from above line is just use ns if, "if" condition is satisfied and launch it with `<node pkg="node_pkg" type="node_type" name="node_name"`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302191/merging-of-launch-files/) by [debonair](https://answers.ros.org/users/37218/debonair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-08-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) on 2018-09-03**:
It is not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want your nodes to be in the same namespace/no namespace? Namespace is an optional [attribute](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes). If @gvdhoorn 's answer is what you were looking for accept it, otherwise elaborate on "combine".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Namespace attributes cannot be empty, so it's not directly possible to make something like that optional I believe.

Something like this might work:

- first launch file:

  ```
   <launch>
     <arg name="use_namespace" default="false" />
     <include file="other.launch"     if="$(arg use_namespace)" ns="my_ns" />
        <include file="other.launch" unless="$(arg use_namespace)" />
   </launch>
  ```
- second launch file (just an example):

  ```
   <launch>
     <param name="la" value="123" />
   </launch>
  ```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [debonair](https://answers.ros.org/users/37218/debonair/) on 2018-09-04**:
what should be my other.launch file contain? just launch node? and we don't specify namespace there?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-04**:\

> what should be my other.launch file contain? just launch node?

whatever you want it to contain. Could launch nodes, include other launch files, everything.

> and we don't specify namespace there?

Exactly.

the first launch file essentially "pushes" the other launch file down into a ns.

**Comment by [debonair](https://answers.ros.org/users/37218/debonair/) on 2018-09-04**:
is it possible to combine include code with if condition in your answer.

**Comment by [debonair](https://answers.ros.org/users/37218/debonair/) on 2018-09-04**:
I had to write node launch code `<node pkg>` with  params twice. one with `if` tag and one with `unless` tag. i was trying to find out way to avoid writing params twice.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-04**:
Which you can do, if you follow my approach.

The "second launch file" has all the nodes without a `ns`. If you start that, nothing will be in a namespace.

The "first launch file" starts the second but *in a namespace*. Don't start the second launch file: no namespace.

No need to duplicate.

**Comment by [debonair](https://answers.ros.org/users/37218/debonair/) on 2018-09-04**:
great. Thanks so much!